# What does Thread.exclusive actually do?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

The information from the API is very sparse - also considering that `Thread.critical` appears not to be documented.

> Wraps a block in Thread.critical, restoring the original value upon exit from the critical section, and returns the value of the block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr:** It makes the given block execute, so that no other ruby-thread can interrupt it.

The [documentation of `Thread.exclusive`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Thread.html#method-c-exclusive) is misleading, as it mentions `Thread.critical=` [which was removed in ruby version 1.9](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/198/topics/10553). However, we can deduce what it does by looking at the ruby source code.

In MRI `Thread.exclusive` is defined in [`prelude.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/prelude.rb). As it is a pretty short file, I'll cite it's content here:

```
class Thread
  MUTEX_FOR_THREAD_EXCLUSIVE = Mutex.new # :nodoc:

  def self.exclusive
    MUTEX_FOR_THREAD_EXCLUSIVE.synchronize{
      yield
    }
  end
end
```

Here the `Thread` class is extended by a static constant `MUTEX_FOR_THREAD_EXCLUSIVE`, which holds a [Mutex](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Mutex.html). When `exclusive` is called, we ask the mutex to `synchronize` execution of the block.

As stated in [Mutex' documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Mutex.html#method-i-synchronize), `synchronize` obtains a lock, runs the block, and releases the lock when the block completes.

Because the mutex is thread-global state, only one single Thread can hold it at the same time.

So this works:

```
# no other Thread can do something between this puts statements
Thread.exclusive do
  puts 1
  puts 2
end
```

But this won't:

```
Thread.exclusive do
  puts 1
  Thread.exclusive do
    puts 2
  end  
  puts 3
end
```

because of this error: `ThreadError: deadlock; recursive locking`.

Comment: I saw that post too, but I still lack a thorough explanation with examples of use.

Comment: @maasha I thought the same and decided to look into the MRI implementation. It turned out to be short enough to understand what it does by reading the code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I am marking it as the correct answer. I do wonder why anyone would use this undocumented method and not Thread and Mutex, which is well described on the internet.

Comment: I found this post because I was looking for a solution to this warning. Thread.exclusive is deprecated, use Mutex
Do you know anything about that?
It's coming from an older version of Rack.
I'll try a newer one but so much stuff still depends on older Rack versions. Poor gem writers. They just can't keep up with Matz. :-D